# Use C# to create a windows service to parse JSON data and insert it into SQL table

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I am a noobie in `JSON`.  In my research I can see the value of using `JSON` versus other api methods but I am having a unique situational issue.

However, my issue lies in trying to parse the `JSON` data.  I have tried three different methods in `C#` to parse the data via a URL and keep getting various errors.  My most recent method I believe will get me exactly what I am looking for but now I am getting a general error when I try to execute the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExecuteRiskSearch();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ExecuteRiskSearch()
{
    string url = "https://localhost/api/getWatchList/EDD9-5FFA-2A6A-3CB9ZCC";

    JObject results = JObject.Parse(url);

    foreach (var result in results["results"])
    {
        string cid = (string)results["CID"];
        JToken rank = results["rank"];

        string risk = "";
        if (rank is JValue)
        {
            risk = (string)rank;
        }
        else if (rank is JArray)
        {
            risk = (string)((JArray)rank).First;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("CID: {0}, Rank:{1}", cid, risk);
    }
}
```

The error occurs on `JObject results = JObject.Parse(url);`

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Can you please indicate why this would be happening?  Am I way off base on this?

Comment: So you expect us the debug your code without knowing anything about your json ? BTW: `JObject.Parse` expects a valid json string, not an URL.

Comment: I think you meant REST rather than JSON.

Comment: I cannot add my json it is sensitive data.  However, the json is pretty basic two fields "CID" and "rank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject.Parse(string json)` doesn't take an url as parameter. You need to download the string and then parse :

```
string url = "https://localhost/api/getWatchList/EDD9-5FFA-2A6A-3CB9ZCC";
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
JObject results = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  However, now I have an error in the foreach statement that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  It appears to be a null reference exception.  I have tried to add null reference IEnumerable to handle empty requests but then the code just exits out with a 0.

Comment: I guess that would be caused by your json. It simply means that the key `results` weren't found on the root element of your json. Double check that if you've got that right. If you need more help, please attach the content of your json here, or at least the very first lines. Use pastebin.com if it is too long.